# discord.js not sending to custom channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made a command that allows for a user to set a moderation channel. The set channel command works and sends the guild ID, and the channel ID into a JSON file like so:

```js
{"781631298749726730":{"channel":"781719843770466355"}}
```

But in my unban command I can't seem to get it to send to the channel that was created inside the `moderationChannel.json` file it just returns with:

```
modChannel.send is not a function
```

Here is the code in the `unban.js` file:

```js
let channels = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("././database/moderationChannel.json", "utf8"))
  
  let modChannel = channels[message.guild.id].channel;

    if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send(`${switchc} You need to provide an ID.`)
    let bannedMember = await bot.user.fetch(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
        if(!bannedMember) return message.channel.send(`${switchc} Please provide a user id to unban someone!`)

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if(!reason) reason = `${switchc} No reason given!`

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send(`${switchc} I dont have permission to perform this command!`)|
    message.delete()
    try {
        message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, reason)
        const bEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor("RANDOM")
.setDescription(`**${bannedMember.tag}** has been unbanned!`)

    message.channel.send(bEmbed)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
let mEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Member Unbanned`)
  .setDescription("I WORK!")
  modChannel.send(mEmbed)
    }
}
```

I used the code for the channels from my prefix command where you set the prefix for a guild. I don't know why it will not work for sending message in a channel set for a certain guild.

If you need the code where we set the channel the code is below.

```js
  let channels = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("././database/moderationChannel.json"));
  
  channels[message.guild.id] = {
    channel: message.channel.id
  }
  
  fs.writeFile("././database/moderationChannel.json", JSON.stringify(channels), (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
  });
  
  let sEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  
  .setColor(aqua)
  .setTitle(`${message.guild.name} Channel Set`)
  .setDescription(`Set to ${message.channel.name}`);
  message.channel.send(sEmbed);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `modChannel` is `message.channel.id`, a simple string, the channel's ID, not the channel that has a `send()` method.

You can replace `let modChannel = channels[message.guild.id].channel` with:

```js
let channelId = channels[message.guild.id].channel;
let modChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);

if (!modChannel) {
  return console.log(`No moderation channel found with ID ${channelId}`);
}
```